# Having Trouble Converting The following Psuedo Code to PHP

Tags: java, php, pseudocode

Deleted old question and added what I have tried so far in PHP
I'm having a major issue converting the following java pseudo code to PHP I've been at this for the last 3 hours and can't get it to work. Can some one please help out.
Basically my main problem is I can't create the correct authorizationToken and because of this my API call keeps failing.

API Request Example (Pseudo Code)

```
String  apiKey             = "Your Api Key";
String  secretKey          = "Your Secret Encryption Key";
int     accountId          = "Your Partner Account Id";
int     siteId             = "Your Site Id";
long    unixTime           =  GetEpoch();

String  encodedApiKey      = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(    apiKey.g‌​‌​etBytes("UTF8") );
String  signatureKey       = encodedApiKey + "|" + accountId + "|" + unixTime;

Mac  sha256Hmac            = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec  keySpec     = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256" );
sha256Hmac.init( keySpec );

byte[]  bytesSignatureHash = sha256Hmac.doFinal( signatureKey.getBytes("UTF8") );
String  authorizationToken = encodedApiKey + "." + Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString( bytesSignatureHash );

String params = "?method=ping&epoch=unixTime&locale=en_US&customerIPAddress={customer ip address}&customerUserAgent={customer user agent}";
String json = "{\"echo\":\"Hello World\"}";

URL  url = new URL("https://api.testapi.com/api/v1.7/" + params);
HttpsURLConnection  conn  = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",   authorizationToken);
conn.setRequestProperty("x-hp-api-siteid", siteId);
conn.setRequestProperty("content-type",    "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( json.getBytes("UTF-8") );
os.close();

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( conn.getInputStream() );
String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

in.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

The following is my php code

```
//  the following is what I've tried so far
$api_key="mykey";
$secret_key="mysecretkey";
$account_id=4345;
$site_id=123;
$unix_time=time(); // Unix Epoch Time


function base64url_encode($data) {
 return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
} 

$encodedApiKey=base64url_encode($api_key);

$signatureKey  = $encodedApiKey."|".$account_id."|".$unix_time;


echo $authorizationToken =$encodedApiKey.".".base64url_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$encodedApiKey, $secret_key,true));

$cust_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$cust_user_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

 //  params just updated this var with epoch=unixTime
 $params = "?method=ping&epoch=unixTime&locale=en_US&customerIPAddress=$cust_ip&customerUserAgent=$cust_user_agent";
$url="https://api.testapi.com/api/v1.7/"$params;
//   comment this out 
/* $json_post=json_encode(array(
"method"=>"ping",
"epoch"=>unixTime,
"customerIPAddress"=>$cust_ip,
"customerUserAgent"=>$cust_user_agent,
"method"=>"ping",

));  */

$headers = array( 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_post), 
'Authorization: '.$authorizationToken,
'x-hp-api-siteid: '.$site_id,
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
); 
    

//INITIATE CURL WEB SERVICES CALL
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POST,1);
//curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_post); // update  just commented it out
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $response = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
echo $h = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
```

Update: with $json_post and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in place the following is the response header and json response I get.

Response Header - Note: X-Auth-Status-Code: 811  (means missing epoch)

Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
ETag: 3E96570154DB9F86CEBAEEF2A203E544
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Server: ABC.COM
Set-Cookie: CFID=358841535; Expires=Sun, 18-Jun-2051 09:40:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: CFTOKEN=c9112fc0099ba33f-996750FC-E74F-91A5-6D464A6C8D3C8759; Expires=Sun, 18-Jun-2051 09:40:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: LOCALE=en%5FUS; Expires=Sun, 18-Jun-2051 09:40:00 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: CURRENCY=USD; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: LANGUAGE=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: SOURCECODE=CheaperBookings; Expires=Wed, 22-Dec-2021 09:40:00 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Auth-Status-Code: 811
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR LAW NID CUR ADMa OUR DELa IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV STA"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-hp-api-siteid,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Fri, 25 Jun 2021 09:39:59 GMT

The JSON Response

{"message":"","code":401,"success":false,"errors":[{"message":""}],"data":"","instance":76,"text":"UNAUTHORIZED","token":"99675141-0ADB-F49B-E3B9EA9A6B5E9CD0"}

Comment: I'm not a Java expert but that looks like it's _probably_ actual Java rather than pseudocode? Can you run that successfully? And what exactly do you mean by "failing"? What response specifically do you get back from the API?

Comment: @ADyson  the code titled pseudo code, was the code I copied and pasted from the API Documentation. Regarding java I haven't wrote java in over 10 years, so I have not tested it. I thought it was going to be simple to write it up using php which I did, but the API call keeps failing with invalid token. I' hit a major roadblock and don't know what else I should try. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It'll be down to the tiny details of the base64 and hmac encoding to see if it generates a valid token. That's why it would be useful to run the Java so you can generate the various variables and see where it starts to differ from the PHP version. Also I think HMAC is dependent on time, so make sure the system clock on the machine where you run the PHP is perfectly in sync with internet time servers.

Comment: Does the API documentation not provide a _verbal explanation_ of the algorithm to be applied?

Comment: @Adyson I just noticed that the response header is returning missing epoch time, but I'm not really sure what that could mean as I have the epoch time in my code. I don't think the machine time is out of sync.

Comment: @CBroe the verbal  explanation pretty much just says "refer to the pseudo code" which I did.

Comment: `I just noticed that the response header is returning missing epoch time`...useful info, thanks. In the Java example, the query data is `?method=ping&epoch=unixTime&locale=en_US...` - this sends the _literal text_ `unixTime` for the "epoch" parameter. It doesn't send the _actual time_, which is what you're doing in the PHP. I think the idea of that is to tell the server what time type you used for calculating the hash, not to include the current time.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed as well that the Java puts the `params` data onto the querystring of the URL. It doesn't encode it to JSON or put it into the request body, which is what you're doing in the PHP. It sends just some junk "hello world" data in the request body (for reasons which are not entirely clear).

Comment: @ADyson Regarding epoch=unixTime  from looking at the code I see unixTime=GetEpoch()  I'm assuming this is the same as php time()  Regarding putting the params instead of JSON I get the following error 
HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Fri, 25 Jun 2021 09:09:20 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 311

Comment: `Regarding epoch=unixTime from looking at the code I see unixTime=GetEpoch() I'm assuming this is the same as php time()`...yes it absolutely is, but it's irrelevant because `unixTime` in that string isn't a variable, it's just plain text. The _variable_ called unixTime is used when creating the signatureKey variable, but isn't used after that.

Comment: `Regarding putting the params instead of JSON I get the following error`....well did you a) reformat the data as a querystring (like the Java example) and b) put some other random JSON into the request body instead (like the Java example)? If you need detailed help, edit the question to show your revised code.

Comment: And did you do the random JSON bit as well? And what response do you get now? Also please note my previous request - don't put code in the comments, edit your question instead. As you can see it isn't very easy to ready in a comment like that! Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson  Sorry about that I took your advice and updated to my latest code. I also tried JSON with no luck additionally I just commented out the JSON in the updated code.

Comment: So you still get Bad Request?

Comment: Btw does the API documentation contain code for the GetEpoch() function? It's not a built-in one as far as I can see. And/or does the docs discuss what the time units should be? It occurs to me the PHP time() function returns the time in _seconds_ whereas many such functions in other languages / libraries return it in _milliseconds_.

Comment: @ADyson  I just updated the response header and the json response I get with the JSON in place. I dont get the Bad Request with the JSON in place I get UNAUTHORIZED","token" with the json post. Please have a look at the bottom portion of my question.

Comment: @ADyson Regarding "Btw does the API documentation contain code for the GetEpoch() function?" it does not contain code for the GetEpoch function. The documentation is not in depth and pretty much just states "refer to the pseudo code "  Regarding the PHP time I just tried it in milliseconds as well with no luck, I'm still getting the same response. I'm stumped as to what the problem could be I feel like I have tried everything at this point.

Comment: yeah I'm running out of ideas too, sorry. Maybe contact the API maintainers then, if their documentation is lacking.